# What is the sensor name and use and circuit diagram for Current TV will be used based on Body parts movement?

Tags: sensor, integrated-circuit, camera, diagram

I want to know more about the Sensor which are used nowadays in the TV and Laptops we can access the functionality by moving our body parts. also used in Game play in Playstations, Laptops to change volume, play music etc...

How can I play with Camera and Digital Image.
Can I create my own sensor technology like when I Up my hand automatic change the song from my music player?

Is it possible?

any SDK is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Kinect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect) from Microsoft is a motion, gesture and sound sensing system that uses a proprietary stereoscopic webcam and microphone to sense physical position, movement and voice commands from the user. While it was originally developed for the XBox 360 gaming console system, it is now a popular and supported peripheral for Windows PCs as well.

[image: Kinect]

Kinect has a [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/), that permits high-level code to accept gesture and movement input. Quoting from the Kinech API page:

> Kinect for Windows gives computers eyes, ears, and the capacity to use them. With Kinect for Windows, thousands of businesses and developers are creating applications that put people first—allowing their customers to interact naturally with computers by simply gesturing and speaking.

For people familiar with Windows / .net software development, the Kinect SDK is known to be very easy to use. A Kinect device will be required for Kinect development, a generic webcam isn't good enough.

Comment: Is there any PHP or Java based SDK available?

Comment: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: is there any Emulator in which we can test this type of SDK or Functionality?

Comment: @AshwinP Not that I know of. Also, developing for an unfamiliar device based on theory / emulation alone is the kind of strategy that gives many developers a bad name, because the application craps out when deployed to a real environment. I would strongly say that's ill-advised.

Comment: right @anindo ghosh Suppose I have Laptop in which Inbuilt Camera or I have SONY XPERIA with Camera ( Front / Back Both ).
And I am creating application in android or Simple HTML5 will it work using that SDK or is it possible to create this type of application for security purpose like Face-detection?

Comment: Or I have Simple Camera at My Home Door and I would like to create app for that to Detect Face and Open Door?
Can you helping me out how can I start and What things initially required to create that app?

Comment: @AshwinP You're describing an entirely different problem now - and one that perhaps belongs more to StackOverFlow than the Electronics StackExchange. Facial feature identification (eyes, nose etc) libraries do exist for Android and for Windows. A much more complex problem, facial recognition, has been done on at least Windoes, but there are no open libraries for the latter than I am aware of. This isn't at all similar to body parts movement identification, which was the original question. And no, Kinect cannot be used with your built-in cameras.

Comment: Oh so for that we must need the Kinect for body movement identification?

Answer (score 2):

Most use a  camera and digital image processing to recognize different body parts and its movements.

Comment: More explanation on How it will be work?

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at the Microsoft Kinect - they've got a SDK for it for use on PC (Windows).

Comment: Perhaps you can also see [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) which is Open Source Computer Vision Library.

Comment: This answer is too short, and should really be a comment.